# React.js won't render properly when changing state for nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

looking for some help here.

I'm implementing nested comment feature like reddit. Basically my data in 'state' look like this:

```
post: {
  id: 'foo'
  comments: [
    { id: '1', comments: [] },
    { id: '2', comments: [ { id: '3', comments: [...]}, ... ]}
  ]
}
```

My code to render the data:

```
<Row>
  <Col md={12}>
   {post.comments.map((comment, index) => {
     return <Comment
              key={comment.id}
              comment={comment} />
    })}
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment.js:

```
render() {
    const comment = this.props.comment;
    return (
     <div>
      <Panel className="comment">
        <Panel.Heading className="commentHeader">
          <div>{comment.id}</div>
      </Panel.Heading>
      <Panel.Body>
        <Row>
          <h3>{comment.content}</h3>
          {comment.comments &&
            comment.comments.map((comment, index) => {
              return <Comment key={comment.id} 
                              comment={comment} />;
              })}
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Button onClick={this.handleReply}> Reply </Button>
        </Row>
      </Panel.Body>
      </Panel>
     </div>
   );
}
```

My problem is when I add outer comment in post react will render fine:

```
post: {
  id: 'foo'
  comments: [
    { id: '1', comments: [] },
    { id: '2', comments: [ { id: '3', comments: [...]}, ... ]},
    { id: 're-render works! see another comment', comments: []},
  ]
}
```

However, if the new 'state' look some thing like this, it will not re-render, but if I reload the page it would be fine:

```
post: {
 id: 'foo',
 comments: [
   { id: '1', comments: [{id: 'not working unless reload page', 
                         comments: []}]},
   { id: '2', comments: [ { id: '3', comments: [...]}, ... ]},
   { id: 're-render works! see another comment', comments: []},
 ]
}
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: how do you update your state?

Comment: there is no error in the console. But I expect to see the inner comment when I update the state but the inner comment won't show. For example:

Initially :
postA:
comment_1
comment_2

After state updated:

postA:
comment_1
  reply_of_comment_1 (this won't show)
comment_2

Comment: @AlbertS I wrote a function in post that used setState then passed it in comment.js. Works fine when I add a comment object in post.

Comment: I am not sure, but react needs to see the state update to rerender the component. So you need to return new comments with added nested comments to make react update your component. If you only add nested data, I think react does not recognize state update. this is why I asked you how you update nested data.

Comment: @AlbertS I believe I did that, return new comments with added nested comments. But it won't update. I console logged in render method and the state actually the newest but the nested comment won't get rendered.

Comment: show code for updates

Comment: @xadm what I did was update the database then pull the latest data back via gralphQL then update the state using setState.

Comment: How many times you see console.log in render function? Does it match with quantity of comments both parents and nested? I am asking do you see that all nested Comment's render functions executed?

Comment: @AlbertS It does not, it is missing the most recently added nested comment. The latest comment function won't executed.

Comment: Okey. You add nested here: { id: '1', comments: [{id: 'not working unless reload page', 
                         comments: []}]}, do you see that comment with id = 1 gets rerended? It seems that react does not see that your parent with id = 1 updated even you have added elements in comments array.

Comment: @AlbertS Yes, it gets rerendered. And yes, it seems that react won't detect that the outter comments get updated. I only can call window.location.reload() which is bad :(

Comment: @AlbertS this is weird, I tried to setState the comments of post to be empty, and in the call back I set it to the newest then it works!!!

Comment: updateComments(comments) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      post: {
        ...prevState.post,
        comments: []
      },
    }), () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        post: {
          ...prevState.post,
          comments: comments,
        }
      }))
    });
  }

Comment: @AlbertS thank you very much I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to offer you the solution:

You try to add the subcomments to the comments. So every comment has to have some id. You click add commment (child or nested) on the some (parent) comment. Then you get parent id and nested data and with some handleCommentAdd function do the following:

```
const handleCommentAdd = (id, nestedData) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      post: {
        ...prevState.post,
        comments: prevState.post.commments.map(comment => (
          comment.id === id ?
          {
            ...comment,
            comments: comment.comments.concat(nestedData)
          } : comment
        ))
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Edit function to match to your state.

If you do not use arrow functions and spread operator:

```
const handleCommentAdd = function(id, nestedData) {
  this.setState(function(prevState) {
    return Object.assign(
      {},
      prevState,
      {post: Object.assign(
        {},
        prevState.post,
        {comments: prevState.post.comments.map(function(comment) {
          comment.id === id ?
          Object.assign(
            {},
            comment,
            {comments: comment.comments.concat(nestedData)}
          ) : comment
        })}
      )}
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: I pulled the latest data directly from the database(in handle add child comment) for each reply to comment so sub-comments are already added to the comments. And I already have the latest data structured.

Comment: see code https://codepen.io/pokaninov/pen/WYdwvw. everything works. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

After data update (existing, mounted) component receives new props - **by default this** (as opposite to state change) **not results with rerender.**

Assuming data is updated and change properly propagates (updated props in dev tools) ... you should use `shouldComponentUpdate` - return true on difference in `prop.comment` (shallow comparison should be enough) - thats all.